# fsockopen() не работает асинхроно

Tags: php, сокет, websocket, hosts, protocol

Попытка асинхронно отправить данные с помощью `fsockopen()` не проходит: без `fgets()` не работает, а с `fgets()`уже перестает быть асинхронным.

```
$sock = fsockopen("ssl://site.ru", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fputs($sock, "GET /file.php?user_id=$user_id HTTP/1.0\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Host: site.ru\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Accept: */*\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "\r\n");
//fgets($sock, 2);
fclose($sock);
```

UPD: с Connection:Close не стартует скрипт:

```
$sock = fsockopen("ssl://site.ru", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fputs($sock, "GET /file.php?user_id=$user_id HTTP/1.0\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Host: site.ru\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Content-Length: 10\r\n");
fputs($sock, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"); 
fclose($sock);
```

Comment: Я думаю ты неверно понимаешь слово "асинхронно". HTTP - это синхронный протокол. То есть, на любой запрос должен быть ответ.
Что ты на самом деле пытаешься сделать?

Comment: @Nikolay, мне нужно из one.php вызвать file.php так, чтобы one.php не ждал от него ответа (так как это занимает продолжительное время). То есть инициализировать запуск file.php. По идеи так должен работать fsockopen, по-крайней мере так много где написано. До этого пробывал exec(), но она вообще не исполняла file.php. Реализация не принципиальна, главное, чтобы one.php не ждал ответа от file.php

Comment: То есть, тебе ответ не важен? "Connection: close" пробовал?

Comment: Если имеется в виду, "отправить ответ, и продолжить работать", то про "connection:close" можно здесь глянуть https://www.zulius.com/how-to/close-browser-connection-continue-execution/

Comment: @Nikolay да, пробывал отправлять заголовок Close, но скрипт не срабатывает. `$sock = fsockopen("ssl://site.ru", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fputs($sock, "GET /file.php?user_id=$user_id HTTP/1.0\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Host: site.ru\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Content-Length: 10\r\n");
fputs($sock, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"); 
fclose($sock);`